# Regular expression for smiles (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string:

```
$str = "Hello:smile: How:flushed: Are you :neckbeard: ?";
```

I want to receive this string:

```
Hello<img src="/img/emoji/smile.png"> How<img src="/img/emoji/flushed.png"> Are you <img src="/img/emoji/neckbeard.png"> ?
```

I construct regular expression:

```
$res = preg_replace('/(.+):([a-z]{1,10}):(.+)/i', '$1<img src="/img/emoji/$2.png" >$3', $str);
```

But this expression replace only last smile. How I can change all smiles for pictures?

Comment: Remove `.+`s: `preg_replace('/:([a-z]{1,10}):/i', '<img src="/img/emoji/$1.png" >', $str)`

Comment: Why are so sure smiles can only contain 1 to 10 symbols?

Answer (score 1):

Only replace the intended part:

```
$res = preg_replace('/:([a-z]{1,10}):/i', '<img src="/img/emoji/$1.png" >', $str);
```

Comment: Really sorry - java mixup :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the replacement to

```
$res = preg_replace('/:([a-z]{1,10}):/i', '<img src="/img/emoji/$2.png" >', $str);
```

You were returnig the whole original string each time the replace took place, so each time it returned the original was restored, minus the last change.